# AsanaNet error in C#

Tags: c#, asana

I am unable to use AsanaNet from C#. When instantiating a new Asana instance, i am unable to pass errorCallback. The error I get is "The errorCallback does not exist in current context". Below is the my code.

```
class Program
{
    private const string _apiKey = "API";
    private static Asana _asana;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Step 1");
        _asana = new Asana(_apiKey, AuthenticationType.Basic, errorCallback);
        var user = new AsanaUser();
        _asana.GetMe(o =>
        {
            user = o as AsanaUser;
        });
        Console.WriteLine("Step 2");
        _asana.GetWorkspaces(o =>
        {
            foreach (AsanaWorkspace workspace in o)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Workspace Name={0}", workspace.Name);
            }
        });
        Console.WriteLine("Step 3");
        _asana.GetWorkspaces(o =>
        {
            foreach (AsanaWorkspace workspace in o)
            {
                _asana.GetProjectsInWorkspace(workspace, projects =>
                {
                    foreach (AsanaProject project in projects)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Project Name=" + project.Name);
                    }
                }
                );
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

Comment: And where is your `errorCallback` declared?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/acron0/AsanaNet/blob/master/AsanaNet/Asana.cs, the constructor has this signature:

```
public Asana(string apiKeyOrBearerToken, AuthenticationType authType, Action<string, string, string> errorCallback)
```

So you can declare your error callback method like this:

```
static void errorCallback(string s1, string s2, string s3)
{

}
```

Also, if you don't want handling anything, you can just pass an empty lambda into constructor:

```
_asana = new Asana(_apiKey, AuthenticationType.Basic, (s1, s2, s3) => {});
```